# What does "error061160_02.xml" mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

What is "error061160_02.xml"? I've tried researching to no avail. Any information would be helpful so that may remove the error from my file. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell something about the context, situation in which you get this error?

You can open the .xml file with a simple text editing program like Windows Notepad and see if it contains some clues.

- XML stands for EXtensible Markup Language

- XML is a markup language much like HTML

- XML was designed to describe data, not to display data

- XML tags are not predefined. You must define your own tags

- XML is designed to be self-descriptive

- XML is a W3C Recommendation

Comment: Unfortunately, the error occurs upon opening the file & does not give any context to a situation in which I get the error. I do have many formulas & conditional formatting throughout, however. I'm beginning to wonder if one of my conditional formats may be the problem. I remember doing some digging & found this particular error is somehow denoting a problem with syntax, which is similar to what you described with this type of error. I'm going to fiddle with the conditional formatting & see if it helps. Thank you very much Gio_sof

Comment: Maybe it helps if you tell what program you use, what file you open, which conditional formats you made? And so on.

Comment: Sure! Excel 2010, a large data file with 400+ Index/Match functions (they pull data from a template within same workbook, conditional formatting makes cells bold when particular cells meet certain criteria..... Thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly, on opening excel, data is imported by some procedure... If imported data  does not meet the specifications of your import procedure then you will see an error. So if you can, you should check the data format of the data you want to import into your excel sheet.
Check for missing columns (data fields) , wrong data types text where integers should be, length of text strings  and so on.
Or adjust your data import specification. Maybe the data changed (extra column etc ?)

Comment: If I understand correctly, on opening excel, data is imported by some procedure... (VBA startup Macro/procedure?). If imported data  does not meet the specifications of your import procedure then you will see an error. So if you can, you should check the data format of the data you want to import into your excel sheet.

Comment: Check for missing columns (data fields) , wrong data types text where integers should be, length of text strings  and so on.
Or adjust your data import specification. Maybe the data changed (extra column etc ?)
Another possibility: your formulas/conditional formatting expects a certain data format but the data(type) changed. So check your data.

Comment: Ok, no missing columns, no macro for importing, rather having functions (formulas) generate information from another worksheet within the same workbook. Data is fine as far as type & where. I think it's my conditional formulas or one of. I'm narrowing it down... Thank you so much for all of your help in going over all of this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... After much process of elimination, I found the problem: it was one of my conditional formulas. I remember doing some research on this particular error & the most frequent response danced around "syntax". I truly believe as Conditional Formulas are used for particular sections/cells of a spreadsheet, the condition is "split up" or diversified among like sections or cells in an attempt to maintain continuity of the formula. Unfortunately, when this happens, it results in broken application of said formula creating a "readability" error, so-to-speak where it doesn't "read correctly to Excel therefore not making sense". This, I've concluded, happens upon adding/removing columns or rows of data in which the conditional formatting is applied.
I removed a particular conditional format that made certain groups of cells bold resulting from identifying specific text in certain named cells. 
I saved the file & reopened..... no error prompt whatsoever. 
I really truly appreciate the feed back & help. Thank you again! Hope it'll be just as smooth next time. Thank you!!!